# MongoDB conversion operators in a Go program

Tags: mongodb, go, bson

I am trying to convert a working mongo query to BSON in Go. I have the basic stuff down and working but am struggling to figure out how to integrate more advanced `in` queries into the mix.

Anyone have a minute to help me convert the following query? It should hopefully give me the direction I need... Unfortunately I have not been able to find many examples outside of just evaluating and queries.

This i think works in mongo:

```
db.mycollection.find({"userId" : {"$in": ["1","2","3"]}})
```

This works in Go:

```
bson.M{"userId": "1"}
```

How do I go about properly introducing the `in` statement?

I tried this:

```
condition = bson.M{
    "userId": bson.M{"$in": userIds},
}
```

but don't seem to work.

Comment: That's how you should do it. If it doesn't work, the error lies somewhere else. Post a [mcve].

Comment: Just to be clear, `userIds` should be a slice of IDs.

Comment: This works fine `colection.Find(ctx, bson.M{"userId": bson.M{"$in": []string{"1","2", "3"}}}, opts)`

Comment: ```userIds``` is a slice of IDs yes.

Comment: @icza you where right, this works. The error lies somewhere else. I will post a minimal reproducible example of my code to reproduce the error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works fine:

```
condition = bson.M{
    "userId": bson.M{"$in": userIds},
}
```

GL guys!